# Insert query in mysql with an auto_increment field

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment, insertion

Ok,

I am sure I am doing something wrong here but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `email_queue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` varchar(4182) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(4182) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(4182) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` varchar(4182) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attempts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
)
```

When I do a

```
insert into email_queue values (1,'','','','','','',0);
```

it works fine and inserts the blank values

but when I try to insert partial values using

```
insert into email_queue(to) values('sample_to_name');
```

it errors out saying 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to) v
alues('sample_to_name')' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to` is mysql [reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) word should be in backticks.

Either avoid the creating column names with Reserved words or enclose them with backtick ``

```
insert into email_queue(`to`) values('sample_to_name');
```

Comment: <dumbFace>That did it for me. Thanks!</dumbFace>

Answer (score 1):

You need back-ticks around to

```
insert into email_queue(`to`) values('sample_to_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is because

```
   to is mysql reserved word
```